# Loop through data frame to extract specific values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to loop through a data frame to extract specific values. I have a loop that states the conditions but I cant get around the indexer out of bounds error.

The loop I have is:

```
new_end = []
for i in range(size):
if fifo.Same_New.iloc[i] == "New" and fifo.Same_New.iloc[i-1] == "New":
    new_end.append(fifo.EndTime.iloc[i])
else:
    if fifo.Same_New.iloc[i] == 'Same' and fifo.Same_New.iloc[i+1] =="New":
        new_end.append(fifo.EndTime.iloc[i])
    else:
        new_end.append('Null')
```

Sample DF:

```
StartTime       EndTime                 Dura    Diff    S/N         
05/01/2024 12:27    05/01/2024 13:04    2224    1036    New
06/01/2024 07:05    06/01/2024 07:06    60      1081    New
06/01/2024 07:06    06/01/2024 07:06    0       0       Same
08/01/2024 10:26    08/01/2024 10:27    32      200     New
08/01/2024 11:45    08/01/2024 11:46    38      78      New
09/01/2024 13:48    09/01/2024 13:51    172     122     New
09/01/2024 16:41    09/01/2024 16:42    60      170     New
09/01/2024 16:43    09/01/2024 17:37    3267    1       Same
09/01/2024 17:38    09/01/2024 17:41    189     1       Same
10/01/2024 10:06    10/01/2024 10:08    142     985     New
10/01/2024 10:51    10/01/2024 10:53    116     43      New
10/01/2024 11:00    10/01/2024 11:00    26      7       New
12/01/2024 12:17    12/01/2024 12:30    752     77      New
15/01/2024 08:01    15/01/2024 08:01    36      1171    New
16/01/2024 15:44    16/01/2024 15:53    577     463     New
16/01/2024 16:43    16/01/2024 17:16    2003    50      New
16/01/2024 17:16    16/01/2024 17:17    69      0       Same
17/01/2024 00:03    17/01/2024 00:04    60      406     New
17/01/2024 00:04    17/01/2024 00:20    943     0       Same
17/01/2024 06:08    17/01/2024 06:09    16      348     New
```

The logic is:

1. If you have to row 1 and row 2 both have "Same" value in S/N column then return EndTime value from row 1. Example below:

```
    05/01/2024 12:27    05/01/2024 13:04    2224    1036    New
    06/01/2024 07:05    06/01/2024 07:06    60      1081    New
```

2. If row 1 has "New" value in S/N column and row 2 has "Same" value in S/N column then return "Null". Example below:

```
    09/01/2024 16:41    09/01/2024 16:42    60      170     New
    09/01/2024 16:43    09/01/2024 17:37    3267    1       Same
```

3. If row 1 has "Same" value in S/N column and row 2 has "Same" value in S/N column then return "Null". Example below:

```
    09/01/2024 16:43    09/01/2024 17:37    3267    1       Same
    09/01/2024 17:38    09/01/2024 17:41    189     1       Same
```

4. If row 1 has "Same" value in S/N column and row 2 has "New" value in S/N column then return End time value from row 1. Example below:

```
    16/01/2024 17:16    16/01/2024 17:17    69      0       Same
    17/01/2024 00:03    17/01/2024 00:04    60      406     New
```

Expected Output would be additional column with those values:

```
StartTime           EndTime          Dura Diff  S/N     N_E
05/01/2024 12:27    05/01/2024 13:04 2224 1036  New     05/01/2024 13:04
06/01/2024 07:05    06/01/2024 07:06 60   1081  New     Null
06/01/2024 07:06    06/01/2024 07:06 0    0     Same    06/01/2024 07:06
08/01/2024 10:26    08/01/2024 10:27 32   200   New     08/01/2024 10:27
08/01/2024 11:45    08/01/2024 11:46 38   78    New     08/01/2024 11:46
09/01/2024 13:48    09/01/2024 13:51 172  122   New     09/01/2024 13:51
09/01/2024 16:41    09/01/2024 16:42 60   170   New     Null
09/01/2024 16:43    09/01/2024 17:37 3267 1     Same    Null
09/01/2024 17:38    09/01/2024 17:41 189  1     Same    09/01/2024 17:41
10/01/2024 10:06    10/01/2024 10:08 142  985   New     10/01/2024 10:08
10/01/2024 10:51    10/01/2024 10:53 116  43    New     10/01/2024 10:53
10/01/2024 11:00    10/01/2024 11:00 26   7     New     10/01/2024 11:00
12/01/2024 12:17    12/01/2024 12:30 752  77    New     12/01/2024 12:30
15/01/2024 08:01    15/01/2024 08:01 36   1171  New     15/01/2024 08:01
16/01/2024 15:44    16/01/2024 15:53 577  463   New     16/01/2024 15:53
16/01/2024 16:43    16/01/2024 17:16 2003 50    New     Null
16/01/2024 17:16    16/01/2024 17:17 69   0     Same    16/01/2024 17:17
17/01/2024 00:03    17/01/2024 00:04 60   406   New     Null
17/01/2024 00:04    17/01/2024 00:20 943  0     Same    17/01/2024 00:20
17/01/2024 06:08    17/01/2024 06:09 16   348   New     17/01/2024 06:09
17/01/2024 06:09    17/01/2024 06:10 30   0     Same    Null
```

Hope it clears it. Sorry for bad formatting It is my first post.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your input, images are not acceptable. Also, clearly explain the expected logic (if your code is incorrect we can't use it to understand the logic) and provide the exact expected output that matches the provided input.

Comment: Edited with samples and output.

Comment: I don't get everything you say but have you tried working with shift instead of looping. Sounds easier to me: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Comment: I have gone through it but could not see how I can use it to get the desired result. I will have another go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify your four conditions into a single one:

- if the next row is a "New', then use the EndTime value, else "Null":

```
df['N_E'] = df['EndTime'].where(df['S/N'].shift(-1).eq('New'), 'Null')
```

Output:

```
           StartTime           EndTime  Dura  Diff   S/N               N_E
0   05/01/2024 12:27  05/01/2024 13:04  2224  1036   New  05/01/2024 13:04
1   06/01/2024 07:05  06/01/2024 07:06    60  1081   New              Null
2   06/01/2024 07:06  06/01/2024 07:06     0     0  Same  06/01/2024 07:06
3   08/01/2024 10:26  08/01/2024 10:27    32   200   New  08/01/2024 10:27
4   08/01/2024 11:45  08/01/2024 11:46    38    78   New  08/01/2024 11:46
5   09/01/2024 13:48  09/01/2024 13:51   172   122   New  09/01/2024 13:51
6   09/01/2024 16:41  09/01/2024 16:42    60   170   New              Null
7   09/01/2024 16:43  09/01/2024 17:37  3267     1  Same              Null
8   09/01/2024 17:38  09/01/2024 17:41   189     1  Same  09/01/2024 17:41
9   10/01/2024 10:06  10/01/2024 10:08   142   985   New  10/01/2024 10:08
10  10/01/2024 10:51  10/01/2024 10:53   116    43   New  10/01/2024 10:53
11  10/01/2024 11:00  10/01/2024 11:00    26     7   New  10/01/2024 11:00
12  12/01/2024 12:17  12/01/2024 12:30   752    77   New  12/01/2024 12:30
13  15/01/2024 08:01  15/01/2024 08:01    36  1171   New  15/01/2024 08:01
14  16/01/2024 15:44  16/01/2024 15:53   577   463   New  16/01/2024 15:53
15  16/01/2024 16:43  16/01/2024 17:16  2003    50   New              Null
16  16/01/2024 17:16  16/01/2024 17:17    69     0  Same  16/01/2024 17:17
17  17/01/2024 00:03  17/01/2024 00:04    60   406   New              Null
18  17/01/2024 00:04  17/01/2024 00:20   943     0  Same  17/01/2024 00:20
19  17/01/2024 06:08  17/01/2024 06:09    16   348   New              Null
```

A more generic method if you want to use different values depending on the conditions would be to use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), but it's really not needed in this case:

```
curr_new  = df['S/N'].eq('New')
curr_same = df['S/N'].eq('Same')

next_row  = df['S/N'].shift(-1)
next_new  = next_row.eq('New')
next_same = next_row.eq('Same')

df['N_E'] = np.select(
          [curr_new&next_new,
           curr_new&next_same,
           curr_same&next_same,
           curr_same&next_new,
          ],
         [df['EndTime'],
          'Null',
          'Null',
          df['EndTime'],
         ], 'undefined')
```

##### last row

The last row is not used since there is no "next row" after it. If you want the mask to be True for the last row in order to assign the End Date, use:

```
df['N_E'] = df['EndTime'].where(df['S/N'].eq('New').shift(-1, fill_value=True),
                                'Null')
```

Or replace `'undefined'` by `df['EndTime']` in the `select`variant.

Output:

```
           StartTime           EndTime  Dura  Diff   S/N               N_E
0   05/01/2024 12:27  05/01/2024 13:04  2224  1036   New  05/01/2024 13:04
1   06/01/2024 07:05  06/01/2024 07:06    60  1081   New              Null
2   06/01/2024 07:06  06/01/2024 07:06     0     0  Same  06/01/2024 07:06
3   08/01/2024 10:26  08/01/2024 10:27    32   200   New  08/01/2024 10:27
4   08/01/2024 11:45  08/01/2024 11:46    38    78   New  08/01/2024 11:46
5   09/01/2024 13:48  09/01/2024 13:51   172   122   New  09/01/2024 13:51
6   09/01/2024 16:41  09/01/2024 16:42    60   170   New              Null
7   09/01/2024 16:43  09/01/2024 17:37  3267     1  Same              Null
8   09/01/2024 17:38  09/01/2024 17:41   189     1  Same  09/01/2024 17:41
9   10/01/2024 10:06  10/01/2024 10:08   142   985   New  10/01/2024 10:08
10  10/01/2024 10:51  10/01/2024 10:53   116    43   New  10/01/2024 10:53
11  10/01/2024 11:00  10/01/2024 11:00    26     7   New  10/01/2024 11:00
12  12/01/2024 12:17  12/01/2024 12:30   752    77   New  12/01/2024 12:30
13  15/01/2024 08:01  15/01/2024 08:01    36  1171   New  15/01/2024 08:01
14  16/01/2024 15:44  16/01/2024 15:53   577   463   New  16/01/2024 15:53
15  16/01/2024 16:43  16/01/2024 17:16  2003    50   New              Null
16  16/01/2024 17:16  16/01/2024 17:17    69     0  Same  16/01/2024 17:17
17  17/01/2024 00:03  17/01/2024 00:04    60   406   New              Null
18  17/01/2024 00:04  17/01/2024 00:20   943     0  Same  17/01/2024 00:20
19  17/01/2024 06:08  17/01/2024 06:09    16   348   New  17/01/2024 06:09
```

Comment: Hi, It does not work on last row. Regardless if it shows Same or New id does not assign the End Date. I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @Kamil there is not next row for the last row, thus the logic is undefined. Do you always want to assign the End Date?

Comment: Yes. If it is the last row it will always grab the End Time from last row. Thanks for quick reply.